# QLPreviewController customise the title color of the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, subclass, qlpreviewcontroller

I can not create a custom QLPreviewController. Can someone help me with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `appearance`

Like this :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```